# Image stretched when viewing on mobile but not when in inspector

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have an image in a flexbox child. When I shrink the screen to mobile-sized on my laptop, the image size adjusts correctly. However, when I view the website on my phone, the image is stretched.

```html
<div className="flex items-center gap-16 flex-col md:flex-row">
    <div className="flex-1 flex gap-7 flex-col items-start">
        ... sibling content
    </div>
    <img src={`/image.png`} className="max-w-100 rounded-lg flex-1 overflow-auto"/>
</div>
```

**Output when viewing mobile size on laptop:**

[image: output on laptop]

**Output when viewing on my phone:**
[image: output on phone]

Comment: IOS or Android?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Image needed to be placed within a container that includes `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```html
<div className="flex-wrap flex-1">
    <img src={`/desktop-mockup.png`} className="max-w-100 rounded-lg flex-1"/>
</div>
```